# Power shell Script store answer and return

Tags: powershell

wonder if anyone can help me, I'm trying to compile a PS script that displays a pop up box with a question, I want it to store the answer and return it to me. I managed to get this script for the pop up with the question but can't find a way of returning the answer back, this could be done with sending email back perhaps?

```
Add-Type

-AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework

$msgBody = "This is a question type your answer"

$msgTitle = "Confirm Reboot"

$msgButton = 'YesNoCancel'

$msgImage = 'Question'

$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)

Write-Host "The user chose: $Result [" ($result).value__ "]"
```

Tried the script that works, need answer returned to my email

Comment: You have the answer right there.  Where is this running that you can't just use the value?

Comment: As for this: ***'...need answer returned to my email'.***  You have no mail code to do mail stuff. Also, this ```($result).value__```, returns a number, not the string from the choice. If it is the string you want then just grab the ```$result```. Also, your message box is not set up to type an answer. It's just a button selection. So, should that next not be, something like, ```make a selection```?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment.

That is what the PowerShell mail cmdlet(s) allow you to do. Just look at the help samples in your PowerShell console/ISE/VSCode instance.
See mail commands ---

```
Get-Command -Name '*mail*'
```

See examples:

```
Get-Help -Name 'Send-MailMessage' -Examples
# Results
<#
SYNOPSIS
    Sends an email message.
    
    
    -- Example 1: Send an email from one person to another person --
    
    Send-MailMessage -From 'User01 <user01@fabrikam.com>' -To 'User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>' -Subject 'Test mail'
#>
```

Get the cmdlet details:

```
Get-Help -Name 'Send-MailMessage' -Detail
```

find the mail modules to download/install and use:

```
Find-module -Name '*mail*'
```

So, based on what you are saying. All-in-all, it could be just this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, 
                       PresentationFramework

$msgBody   = "Make a selection"
$msgTitle  = "Confirm Reboot"
$msgButton = 'YesNoCancel'
$msgImage  = 'Question'
$Result    = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)


$MailProperties = @{
    From    = 'User01 <user01@fabrikam.com>'
    To      = 'User02 <user02@fabrikam.com>'
    Subject = 'Results from user app response'
    Body    = "The user chose: $Result"
}
Send-MailMessage @MailProperties
```

Well, you need to give it a mail server to work with as well.

Update as per our last comment exchange.

Note: I am using a PowerShell feature called, ***Variable Squeezing***, in order to assign a value to a variable and output to the screen at the same time. This is not needed on the code to do what you are after, but it shows you your variable contents before they are processed later in your code.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, 
                    PresentationFramework

$msgBody   = "Make a selection"
$msgTitle  = "Confirm Reboot"
$msgButton = 'YesNoCancel'
$msgImage  = 'Question'
($Result   = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage))
# Results
<#
Yes
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, 
                    PresentationFramework

$msgBody   = "Make a selection"
$msgTitle  = "Confirm Reboot"
$msgButton = 'YesNoCancel'
$msgImage  = 'Question'
($Result   = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage))
# Results
<#
No
#>

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, 
                    PresentationFramework

$msgBody   = "Make a selection"
$msgTitle  = "Confirm Reboot"
$msgButton = 'YesNoCancel'
$msgImage  = 'Question'
($Result   = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage))
# Results
<#
Cancel
#>
```

Comment: Thanks looking at the script postanote !

Comment: Thanks looking at the script postanote ! In a nutshell what you suggested is what im looking to compile, how could i go to save the answer on a string and have a mail sent with the answer (yes/no) automatically based on the user whom is submitting the result. SO:  User answers Yes/no this answer is saved on a string and emailed back to me is there any attribute i can add so powershell can automatically populate the from based on user email or username?

Comment: No worries. Yet , just know, there is no concept/vehicle to compile a .ps1 (PowerShell Script) file. You write them and run them.  As for this, ```Yes/no```, response thing, you already have that in the $result. There is no need for the dot referencing of the value. So, what I posted would get you what you are after. If you just run the first part and just check ```$Result```, you'll see what was returned as a string. If you dot-source reference he value, it is always a number.